# How to do proper integration testing with Pac4j OAuth2 and Undertow?

Tags: java, session, undertow, pac4j

I can't figure out how to log in a fake/mock user with Pac4J OAuth2 and Undertow server, and use it in tests (everything works fine with the real setup).
I made this fake client to use instead of real ones:

```scala
class FakeGitHubClient(userProfile: UserProfile) extends OAuth20Client {

  setCallbackUrl("http://local.test")

  reinit()

  override protected def internalInit(forceReinit: Boolean): Unit = {
    val creds = new TokenCredentials("fake-token")
    creds.setUserProfile(userProfile)

    defaultCredentialsExtractor((ctx, store) => ju.Optional.of(creds))
    defaultAuthenticator((cred, ctx, store) => cred.setUserProfile(userProfile))

    super.internalInit(forceReinit)
  }
```

This is the part where I extract the user profile from session:

```
    val sessionStore = FindBest.sessionStore(null, config, new UndertowSessionStore(exchange))

    val profileManager = config.getProfileManagerFactory().apply(new UndertowWebContext(exchange), sessionStore)

    profileManager.getProfile().toScala.flatMap { profile =>
      val identityProvider = profile match
        case _: GitHubProfile  => "github"
        case _: Google2Profile => "google"
        case _                 => "unknown"
      val identityProviderId = profile.getId()
      userEntityDao.findBySocialId(identityProvider, identityProviderId)
    }
```

The `getProfile` always returns an empty `Optional`..
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you publish your whole test somewhere?